# Losing selector after $.get in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I read all the `<li>` on the page, submit a request to an other page via Ajax. Its all good.

The only problem I have is updating the `<li>` after the request has comeback. Outside the `$.get`, `$li` or `$(this)` is the current `<li>`. INSIDE the `$.get`, `$li` is always the last `<li>` on the page and that is my problem.

```
//For each <li>
$('ul#clients li').each(function(index) {
    $li = $(this);
    $li.append('This is ok');

    //Update Data via Ajax
    $.get("/ajax-update.php", function(data) {  $li.append('This is not OK!'); });

}
```

Comment: this is a scope issue - `$li` is not defined in the scope of your anonymous function...

Comment: nitpick: change your selector to #clients li, the ul before the ID is unnecessary

Comment: jbabey - if the javascript is shared over different pages as is sometimes the case then it can cause problems if you have another element with id=clients on another page if you do it that way. Plus its good practice to do it this way, there's nothing wrong with being thorough.

Comment: @ThomasClayson There is something wrong with being thorough and that is the performance loss. In fact, the best way to write it is `$('#clients').find('li')` as long as performance is a concern.

Comment: Akkuma is there a performance loss between `$('ul#clients')` and `$('#clients')`. I would have thought narrowing down the selector to only `ul`s would increase performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `var`... Without the `var` prefix, a variable will be defined at the closest parent scope where `$li` is declared. If `$li` has never been declared, it will be defined in the global (`window`) scope.

```
//For each <li>
$('ul#clients li').each(function(index) {
    var $li = $(this);
    $li.append('This is ok');

    //Update Data via Ajax
    $.get("/ajax-update.php", function(data) {  $li.append('This is not OK!'); });

}
```

Comment: @DaveNewton No it is not. Have a look at the first two sentences of my answer.

Comment: Hmm, didn't see those two sentences before a refresh.

Comment: Not sure if using global variables thus polluting the global scope is the best solution

Comment: @FernandoDiazGarrido I don't see any global variable declarations in my answer. At your answer, however, I see `$li` becoming a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that $.get is asyncronous. That means that it runs on a separate thread. So before that thread completes its already run through the other li's and each time its changing the $li variable.

So when all the $.get's return its on the last $li, which is why you're seeing only the last li change.

I think you can use `var`. This should limit the scope of the variable to the current loop and solve the problem.

Otherwise you might need to include a count variable outside the each variable and use an array to store the li objects. If you need some more info regarding this let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the context parameter to specify the context of the callbacks. Note this is only available in the ajax method and not for get, but the result is the same

```
$('ul#clients li').each(function(index) {
  $li = $(this);
  $li.append('This is ok');

  $.ajax({
    url: "/ajax-update.php",
    context: this,
    success: function(){
      $(this).append('This is not OK!');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Personally I think this is sidestepping a big nasty problem, creating a global variable that probably is not intended to be global.

Comment: @Akkuma there is no global variables in my example, I just pass the context, all the other answers suggest using global variables but mine

Comment: How is `$li` not sitting in global context in your example? Yes, you're binding the ajax to a context and resolving the issue, but you're still creating a global variable. Both Rob W and I agree on this. None of the other examples are suggesting to use global variables.

Comment: Ouups very true, I skipped that from the copy/paste, still the method does not make use of the global scope, would still work with li as a local variable

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of your problem and a comment how to fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/Akkuma/AJnR4/

What is happening is that your `$li` is created on the global scope. Due to `$.get` being asynchronous your `$li`'s value is set to the last value before the first `$.get` even returns to your success function. You could consider this a race condition. If the `$.get` were so fast that it executed before the next iteration of the loop, you would actually not see know this problem existed.

The simple solution, as the comment shows, is to change `$li` to `var $li` to keep it scoped properly.